# Kafka - which value will be considered as final

Tags: apache-kafka

In one of the deployments, ops team made a mistake and had different values for `min.insync.replicas` in `server.properties`.

- Broker 1  : 2
- Broker 2  : 3
- Broker 3  : 4

Broker 3 is the controller.

Which value will considered as final for `min.insync.replicas`

Comment: I suppose that it is set to the value specified in the broker that  is started last.

Comment: That's overridable at a topic setting anyway, but it will ultimately depend where partitions exist for any given topic

Comment: @OneCricketeer, would you mind elaborating it further as how it depends ? and which value will be considered as the "ultimate" value for  "min.insync.replicas"

Comment: 1) I have never differed this setting because I (correctly) use configuration management software to ensure there can only ever be a single value for any server config 2)  I say it depends because you have partitions stored on brokers, not entire topics. Replicas are tracked _per broker_, not _per topic_, therefore, I doubt there is such a "ultimate" value, but rather _it depends_ where your topic partitions are actually stored

Comment: got it. thanks. Please add it as a response, i will accept it as answer if you would like :-)